# xslt copy element value if not null to a new element that may not exist

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml below.

```xml
<truck>
   <time1>1234</time1>
   <time2>5678</time2>
</truck>
```

I want to copy the value of time2 to time 1 if the time2 value is not empty.
Time2 and Time 1 are both optional and one or both could not be present.
If Time 2 is present and has a value I want to override time1 value or create time1 with that element.

Output from above:

```
<truck>
   <time1>5678</time1>
   <time2>5678</time2>
</truck>
```

Example 2

```
<truck>
   <time2>5678</time2>
</truck>
```

Example 2 Output

```
<truck>
   <time1>5678</time1>
   <time2>5678</time2>
</truck>
```

Example 3

```
<truck>
   <time1>1234</time1>
</truck>
```

Example 3 Output

```
<truck>
   <time1>1234</time1>
</truck>
```

I tried this xslt transformation but it didnt work.

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='time2']">
    <xsl:if test="not(*[.=''])">
        <time1>
            <xsl:value-of select="time2"/>
        </time1>
        <time2>
            <xsl:value-of select="time2"/>
        </time2>

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry copy and paste error. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="truck[time2]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <time1>
            <xsl:value-of select="time2"/>
        </time1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="time2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to put anything in the time 1 tag. the time 1 element isn't populated when I have a time 2 value? Any suggestion?

Comment: @jonnysteals You can see it working with all of your 3 examples here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEa.